# how to use play.api.mvc.Security class to check user is authenticated or not?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am beginer to scala and want to implement simple user login in my app.
If user is valid user redirect to index page otherwise redirect to login page.

how do I implement above using security class in play???

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this module, its easy to integrate and have what you looks for, have examples for both scala and java:

[Secure Social Module](http://securesocial.ws/)